# Cannot find module 'ejs' on opentok sample

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, opentok

I am following this guide:
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-node/tree/master/sample/HelloWorld

The project compiles fine, but when I start, I get this error:

Error:

```
> Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at new View (C:\pruebaTokbox\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:80:30)
>     at Function.render (C:\pruebaTokbox\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
>     at ServerResponse.render (C:\pruebaTokbox\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
>     at C:\pruebaTokbox\index.js:33:7
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\pruebaTokbox\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (C:\pruebaTokbox\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

My code:
package.json

```
{
  "name": "opentok-helloworld-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Group video chat app to demonstrate the basic functionality of OpenTok",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^0.8.6",
    "express": "^3.5.0",
    "opentok": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express'),
    OpenTok = require('opentok');

// Verify that the API Key and API Secret are defined
var apiKey = 111111,
    apiSecret = '1111111';
if (!apiKey || !apiSecret) {
  console.log('You must specify API_KEY and API_SECRET environment variables');
  process.exit(1);
}

// Initialize the express app
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Initialize OpenTok
var opentok = new OpenTok(apiKey, apiSecret);

// Create a session and store it in the express app
opentok.createSession(function(err, session) {
  if (err) throw err;
  app.set('sessionId', session.sessionId);
  // We will wait on starting the app until this is done
  init();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var sessionId = app.get('sessionId'),
      // generate a fresh token for this client
      token = opentok.generateToken(sessionId);

  res.render('index.ejs', {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    sessionId: sessionId,
    token: token
  });
});

// Start the express app
function init() {
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('You\'re app is now ready at http://localhost:3000/');
  });
}
```

and index.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>OpenTok Hello World</title>
    <script src="//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/TB.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var apiKey = '<%= apiKey %>';
        var sessionId = '<%= sessionId %>';
        var token = '<%= token %>';
    </script>
    <script src="/public/js/helloworld.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello, World!</h2>

    <div id="publisher"></div>

    <div id="subscribers"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The original file, didnt have the public path, just JS, but that path was wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOFSA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to execute these 2 commands

- npm install ejs --save
- npm install express --save

Comment: note that since you have a package.json file you don't need to execute two npm commands. you can install all your dependencies using 'npm i' or 'npm install' -> this command check the deps in your package.json file and install everything under the 'dependencies' property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `view engine` in your index.js:

Add this to your file:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

That should fix it.

Ps: just as a sanity check, make sure that ejs is actually installed by running `npm i ejs`